# Local variables in bash functions taking option arguments

Tags: bash, function

Have been using `local` in my bash functions after matching argument options.

----- plist -----

```
local fdir=${dpath:-$PWD}
pregion "${ropts[@]}"
```

----- pregion -----

```
("-d"|"--directory")
  local fdir=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
...
# later on
: ${fdir:="${@:$#}"}
```

But the approach produced a problem when I called the following in `pregion`.

```
: ${fdir:="${@:$#}"}
```

Because `fdir` is being set in `plist`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem actually is. Does fdir have the wrong value at some point in the script? Are you using `local` in all your functions? Is it correct to localize this variable at all?

Comment: As written the question should be closed because you're asking for opinions, and the question is, IMO, overly broad -- ref [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on stackoverflow is worth reading too.

Comment: Declare them local at the start of the function, outside any conditions and before they're used for anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. `local` means the variable is visible (read/write) in that function *and in any function called by it* (and any function called by *those*, etc).
2. You're using `local` in a case branch: what happens if the -d option is not passed? Then that variable is not local. Is that what you're seeing?

Without seeing more of your code, I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: You are correct, when the `-d` is not passed, `: ${fdir:="${@:$#}"}` will not execute because it was set by the parent function for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` like in most shells¹ `local`/`typeset` do *dynamic* scoping. Variables declared local in a function are not only local / visible to that function.

The only thing that happens is that upon invoking `local` (the first time in the function), a new instance of the variable is created which shadows the corresponding variable in the parent scope, and when the function returns, that variable is destroyed and the one *underneath* restored. The variable is still seen by any code run within including other functions.

For  a shell with *static* scoping, you'd need to switch to ksh93 (and use the `function f { ...; }` style of function definition (not the `f() { ...; }` Bourne-style one), or zsh and use its `private` builtin.

```
$ ksh -c 'function f { typeset a=1; echo "f: $a"; g; }; function g { echo "g: $a"; }; a=0; f'
f: 1
g: 0
$ zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/param/private; f() { private a=1; echo "f: $a"; g; }; g() { echo "g: $a"; }; a=0; f'
f: 1
g: 0
$ bash -c 'f() { local a=1; echo "f: $a"; g; }; g() { echo "g: $a"; }; a=0; f'
f: 1
g: 1
```

See how in `bash` `g` sees the `$a` of its `f` parent, while in `ksh93` (or `zsh` where `f` had declared `$a` *private* before invoking `g`), `g` sees the `$a` of the global scope.

In your case in `bash` though, you don't want `pregion` to consider the `$fdir` in the global scope, so all you need to do is declare your `fdir` local and without a value before starting assigning anything to it:

```
pregion() {
  local fdir # declares it unset (as long as the localvar_inherit
             # option is not set).
  ...
   ("-d"|"--directory")
     fdir=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
  ...
  # later on
  : "${fdir=${@:$#}}"
  ...
}
```

Also note that you had the quotes in the wrong place in <strike>`: ${fdir:="${@:$#}"}`</strike> causing the expansion to be subject to split+glob. Also note that `${var:=value}` assigns `value` to `$var` if `$var` was previously *empty*, while you likely want it if `$var` was previously *unset*, that is if `fdir=$2` above was not run for which the syntax is `${var=value}`.

Here, you could also do:

```
pregion() {
  local fdir="${@:$#}"
  ...
   ("-d"|"--directory")
     fdir=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
  ...
}
```

That is unconditionally assign the last positional parameter to `$fdir` first, and then later override it if `-d` was passed.

More generally, you'd want to declare all your local variables as local before you start using them and in a shell with dynamic scoping, choose some naming convention for your *global* variables to  make sure they don't clash with local variables. All uppercase variables is common for that, though you may need to consider the potential clashing with well known *environment* variables.

---

<sup>¹ including ksh83 - ksh88 where local scoping with typeset was introduced and the  shell that bash mostly mimics, and the Almquist shell where the `local` command was introduced (though which works differently in this instance in that local variables inherit the value and attributes of the variable in the parent scope; see the `localvar_inherit` option in later versions of bash to get a similar behaviour)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128042/discussion-on-answer-by-stephane-chazelas-local-variables-in-bash-functions-taki).